# Доступ к диску С

Tags: ос

Здрастуйте! Помогите пожалуйста! Комп в сети, надо было сделать чтобы диски были доступны с других компов, но как то получилось что диск С стал вообще не доступен. Что нужно сделать? Заранее благодарна всем кто поможет?

Comment: ос... какая ос?!

Answer (score 1):

Открытие доступа к сети осуществляется командой net share

```
net share share=C:\Users\Someone\Share
```

Монтирование диска осуществляется командой net use

```
net use C:\\server\share /user:Accounts\Someone
```

Для вывода полной справки

```
net help share
```

или

```
net help use
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте админские шары `\\<computer_name>\<disk_letter>$\`

Да кстати забудьте об расшаривании дисков это не безопасно!!

Создавайте специализированные папки для этих нужд вроде c:share